# Android Room Porblem: protected void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db)

Tags: android, firebase

**this is the error code**

```
C:\Users\huh\AndroidStudioProjects\test\app\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\out\com\name\test\database\AppDatabase_Impl.java:56: error: onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in <anonymous com.droidbane.test.database.AppDatabase_Impl$1> cannot override onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase) in Delegate
      protected void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
                     ^
  attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

*Can you at least share my mistake or your Room code that you used or could give an example?*

this is my error code and it leads me here: (AppDatabase_Impl.java)

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
      for (int _i = 0, _size = mCallbacks.size(); _i < _size; _i++) {
        mCallbacks.get(_i).onCreate(_db);
      }
    }
  }
```

[This is the list I followed](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

**folder layout**

```
com.name.test
 ┣ database
 ┃ ┗ AppDatabase.java
 ┃ ┗ Words.java
 ┃ ┗ WordsDao.java
 ┣ MainActivity.java
```

**AppDataBase.java**

```
 package com.name.test.database;
    
    import androidx.room.Database;
    import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
    
    @Database(entities = {Words.class}, version = 1)
    public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
        public abstract WordsDao wordsDao();
    }
```

**Words**

```
package com.name.test.database;

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity
public class Words {

    @PrimaryKey
    public int uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "words")
    public String words;
}
```

**WordsDao**

```
package com.name.test.database;

import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface WordsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM words")
    List<Words> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Words... words);

    @Delete
    void delete(Words words);
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.name.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.room.Room;

import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import com.droidbane.test.database.AppDatabase;
import com.droidbane.test.database.Words;
import com.droidbane.test.database.WordsDao;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }

    public void ChangeTextClick(View view) {

        AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();


        WordsDao wordsDao = db.wordsDao();
        List<Words> words = wordsDao.getAll();
        Log.w("asd", "ChangeTextClick: " + words);
    }
}
```

Is this error caused by me or is it due to the document? Are the codes old? Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Since it's a bout Room, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-room-using-kotlin-flow-in-jetpack-compose-7a720dec35f5) will help.

Comment: `@Override public void onCreate(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) { ... }`

Comment: Check the room version in all project modules, they should be the same

Answer (score 6):

Just make all following dependencies to the same version:

```
//Room database
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.1"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:2.5.1"
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by decreasing the version:

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.2'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.2'
// optional - RxJava2 support for Room
implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava2:2.2.2'
// optional - RxJava3 support for Room
implementation 'androidx.room:room-rxjava3:2.4.2'
// optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
implementation 'androidx.room:room-guava:2.2.2'
// optional - Test helpers
testImplementation 'androidx.room:room-testing:2.2.2'
// optional - Paging 3 Integration
implementation 'androidx.room:room-paging:2.4.2'
```

Comment: Solved the same problem by making room testing dependency version the same as the rest: `implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"`

Answer (score 3):

For those who have the same problem, this is due to the simultaneous use of
`annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"` and `kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"`. Just remove one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i dind't have the dependency problem, but I have the same error. I just *clean project and rebuild the code again*, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when updating a third party lib version. It seems it was depending on a newer version of room, so it "got fixed" by just updating to the last room version ( 2.4.3 to 2.5.0 in my case ).